# Input connector problems in custom modelica models with custom media

Tags: modelica

I am currently working with a Modelica model in Dymola to simulate a chemical process. The reactor modeling itself is done to a satisfying extent, but I'm having a hard time implementing these models into Modelica, especially with respect to getting the various Media definitions to interconnect and communicate, so to speak. This is also the key achievement of the Modelica implementation of the model.

At the moment I'm struggling with a specific type of error which, even though it appears quite obvious and straight-forward, I find relatively hard to solve. The errors are of the type:

```
Note: The input connector p of coopolReactor_2706_1.medium is not connected from the outside.
It is likely that it should have been connected, and recursive check will assume this.
The missing connection is a likely cause of errors in the model.

Note: The input connector h of coopolReactor_2706_1.medium is not connected from the outside.
It is likely that it should have been connected, and recursive check will assume this.
The missing connection is a likely cause of errors in the model.
The model has the same number of unknowns and equations.
The model has the same number of unknowns and equations.

The model EmulsionPolymerizationToolbox.Test.Test_2706 component coopolReactor_2706_1 is structurally singular.
when assuming the most generic outside couplings to all the flow variables of its connectors.
```

In the specific code which gave this error message, I've mimic'ed a simple lumped volume extending base classes from the Modelica Standard Library, but the error is still the same as for my complete reactor models. That's why understanding and solving this problem is vital to the progress of my assignment.

I've been searching a bit online to find out more about what could cause this problem, without much luck. Could someone please elaborate a bit on these kind of errors, and maybe even suggest solutions? Any inputs from this board will be useful to me.

Thanks in advance.

Regards, Fredrik.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible this is actually a [Red Herring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring).  It appears as though this message is generated because of an imbalance in equations.  Dymola then searches for the source.  It may be that when it seems an imbalance in your component, it also notices that you have an unconnected input and reports that, even if that may not be your problem.

Another thing to keep in mind is that one of the new features in Modelica 3.x was the addition of rules about local balancing of equations and unknowns.  One impact of these rules was that for medium models to be balanced, it was necessary to mark some of the variables as inputs (implying they would be specified from the outside).  This use of the `input` qualifier isn't meant to indicate that these variables need to be connected to (or even specified via equations or modifications).  Instead, it is really just a way of indicating how many equations are provided by the media model and how many are provided outside.

So where does this leave you.  Well, I could be completely wrong (let's not overlook that possibility).  But if I'm right, this indicates that you have an imbalance that has nothing to do "unconnected inputs".  I suppose the only real help my answer gives is to encourage you to look for other "missing" equations.

If you actually posted code of your simple case, someone might be able to spot the missing equation.